# RxJava2 How to share an observable with two other observer, and merge it back to a subscriber

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have the following methods

```
Document createDocument(String url);
List<MediaContent> getVideo(Document doc);
List<MediaContent> getImages(Document doc);
```

List<  MediaContent> will be consumed by

```
void appendToRv(List<MediaContent> media);
```

I like to use RxJava2 such that

```
CreateDocument -> getVideo   ->
                             -> appendToRv  
               -> getImages  ->
```

(also, the video output should be ordered before images).

How would I go about doing that? I tried flatMap, but it seems to only allow a single method to be used

```
Single<List<MediaContent>> single = 
    Single.fromCallable(() -> createDocument(url))

      // . ?? .. 
      // this is the part i am lost with
      // how do i feed document to -> getVideo() and getImage()
      // and then merge them back into the subscriber 
      // 
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

single.subscribe(parseImageSubscription);
```

The DisposableSingleObserver

```
parseImageSubscription = new DisposableSingleObserver<List<MediaContent>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<MediaContent> media) { 
        if(media!=null) {
            appendToRv(media);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable error) { 
        doSnackBar("error loading: '" + q + "'");
    }
};
```

the single observables for getVideos and getImages

```
Single<List<MediaContent>> SingleGetImage(Document document ) {
    return Single.create(e -> {
        List<MediaContent> result = getImage(document);
        if (result != null) {
            e.onSuccess(result);
        }else {
            e.onError(new Exception("No images found"));
        }
    });
}

Single<List<MediaContent>> singleGetVideo(Document document ) {
    return Single.create(e -> {
        List<MediaContent> result = getVideo( document);
        if (result != null) {
            e.onSuccess(result);
        }else {
            e.onError(new Exception("No videos found"));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you want to execute in parallel the `getVideos` and `getImages` requests, you can use `flatMap()` with `zip()`, zip will collect the 2 emissions from both `Singles`, and you can combine the 2 results to a new value, meaning you can sort the videos `MediaContent` list , and combine it with the images `MediaContent` list, and return unified list (or whatever other object you'd like):

```
Single<List<MediaContent>> single =
            Single.fromCallable(() -> createDocument(url))
                    .flatMap(document -> Single.zip(singleGetVideo(document), SingleGetImage(document),
                            (videoMediaContents, imageMediaContents) -> //here you'll have the 2 results
                    //you can sort combine etc. and return unified object
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

    single.subscribe(parseImageSubscription)
```

Answer (score 1):

Observable.zip() could implement it perfect. The Observer will receive a merged result by this method.

```
public void zip() {
    Observable<Integer> observable1 = Observable.just(1);
    Observable<Integer> observable2 = Observable.just(2);
    Observable.zip(observable1, observable2, new Func2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call(Integer integer, Integer integer2) {
            return integer + integer2;
        }
    }).subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Integer o) {
            Logger.i(o.toString());
            //Here will print 3.
        }
    });
}
```